# How to search through rows and assign column value based on search in Postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm creating an application similar to Twitter. In that I'm writing a query for the profile page. So when the user visits someone other users profile, he/she can view the tweets liked by that particular user. So for that my query is retrieving all such tweets liked by that user, along with total likes and comments on that tweet.

But an additional parameter I require is whether the current user has liked any of those tweets, and if yes, I want it to retrieve it as boolean True in my query so I can display it as liked in UI.

But I don't know how to achieve this part. Following is a sub-query from my main query

```
    select l.tweet_id, count(*) as total_likes, 
           <insert here> as current_user_liked
      from api_likes as l 
INNER JOIN accounts_user ON l.liked_by_id = accounts_user.id 
     group by tweet_id
```

Is there an inbuilt function in postgres that can scan through the filtered rows and check whether current user id is present in `liked_by_id`. If so mark `current_user_liked` as True, else False.

Comment: This can be resolved with subquery/aggregate functions in postgres. Are you looking for a postgres SQL statement to solve this, or a django queryset? Could you share the relevant data models or the postgres table definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You want to left outer join back into the `api_likes` table.

```
    select l.tweet_id, count(*) as total_likes, 
           case
             when lu.twee_id is null then false
             else true
           end as current_user_liked
      from api_likes as l 
INNER JOIN accounts_user ON l.liked_by_id = accounts_user.id 
 left join api_likes as lu on lu.tweet_id = l.tweet_id
                          and lu.liked_by_id = <current user id>
     group by tweet_id
```

This will continue to bring in the rows you are seeing and will add a row for the `lu` alias on `api_likes`.  If no such row exists matching the `l.tweet_id` and the current user's `id`, then the columns from the `lu` alias will be `null`.